# Why am I getting a StaleElementReferenceException even though it found the element on the page?

Tags: python, selenium

I am building a web scraper of sorts in Python using Selenium. I am iterating through a loop, the beginning of each iteration of which will go back to the main page. On the first iteration, everything works seamlessly. However, on the second iteration, it will throw a StaleElementReferenceException on the last line:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Here is my code:

```
    for link in links:
        #Go to MP3 converter homepage
        self.__driver.get("http://convert2mp3.net/en/")         

        #Type in the video link
        urlinput = self.__driver.find_element_by_id("urlinput") 

        #TEST
        print(str(urlinput))

        self.__action.send_keys_to_element(urlinput, "https://www.youtube.com" + link + Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

The test in the code was to it prove that it is actually able to fetch the element from page. It prints out the following:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="509fc04e4130a25f46f6068684b97a1a", element="0.9812681457094412-1")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="509fc04e4130a25f46f6068684b97a1a", element="0.36225331932442084-1")>
```

So, as you can see, it goes through almost two complete iterations, but will crash on the last line of the second iteration.

Previously, I also put in a test case to output the whole page source to a text file. The element is in fact loaded by the time it gets to the error line, and the element I'm fetching is in fact in that source file. I'm not sure why it fails to work after one time.

**EDIT:** Someone in the comments asked me to show how I defined links:

```
    yt_url = req.urlopen(vid_link)
    #Note here that 'sopa' is BeautifulSoup
    yt_page = sopa(yt_url, "html.parser")

    #Get all links
    temp_links = yt_page.find_all("a", href = True)
    links = []

    #Filter playlist to get just the video links
    for l in temp_links:
        if l["href"] not in links and "index" in l["href"] and  l["href"].startswith("/watch"):
            links.append(l["href"])

    return links
```

Comment: *for link in links*... What are those links? `links` is the list of WebElements?

Comment: They're part of a URL. I also previously ran test cases to make sure they were printing out they were supposed to. They are.

Comment: Show how you defined `links`

Comment: Look at the edit in the post

Comment: when you do an action and the page reloads, the elements are different. you have to refind the elements after an action.

Comment: @HenningLuther

Is that not what I did? I have:

`urlinput = self.__driver.find_element_by_id("urlinput")`

in the for loop; am I not refinding the element with each iteration?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

After some further tinkering, I found the answer. In my for loop, I was indeed finding the element again, but what I didn't realize was that Selenium wanted me to also update the ActionChain again. I had initialized it in the constructor, but I added the following line of code right below the beginning of the for loop:

```
        self.__action = chain.ActionChains(self.__driver)
```

and it worked.

I had assumed that since I had passed a reference to self.__driver the first time, it would have updated information whenever I got a new web address from the driver, but that does not appear to be the way Selenium does things.